# How to create a UIImage from Facebook response data?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, uiimage

I use the following code to download the profile picture from a Facebook user’s friends array:

```
NSString *urlString = friendData[@"picture"][@"data"][@"url"];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
                                                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                      timeoutInterval:2.0f];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest 
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] 
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *resp, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
}];
```

`urlString` is valid, i.e. I can open it in Safari, and I do see the picture there.

In the completion handler, `error` is `nil`, and `data` has 1583 bytes.
However, `image` is initialized as `nil`, i.e. `image` could not be initialized from the specified data.

What is wrong with my code?

EDIT (due to the comment of rckoenes):

`resp` contains the following data:

```
{ status code: 200, headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    "Cache-Control" = "max-age=1209600, no-transform";
    "Content-Length" = 1583;
    "Content-Type" = "image/jpeg";
    Date = "Thu, 01 Oct 2015 09:19:41 GMT";
    Expires = "Thu, 15 Oct 2015 08:08:18 GMT";
    "Last-Modified" = "Thu, 01 Oct 2015 06:36:27 GMT";
    "timing-allow-origin" = "*";
} }
```

Comment: The response might not be image data, try and create a `NSString` with the response data and see what you get,

Comment: But I can open the same URL in Safari and I do see the image; so it should be some kind of image format.

Comment: Maybe it is a header issue with your request. It is worth a try, it just one line code you can easily debug.

Comment: you can use asynchronous class for get server url to uiimage?

Comment: @Rohitsuvagiya as you can see from the posted code it is already asynchronous.

Comment: @rckoenes How do I create the string? Using [NSString stringEncodingForData:data encodingOptions:xxx]? Which encoding options should I use?

Comment: you are use asynchronous class?

Comment: @rckoenes Sorry, stupid question. I have edited my question...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

Download AsyncImageView Class [Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64062310/ASYNC_IMAGE.zip)

.M File

```
#import "AsyncImageView.h"

NSString *urlString = friendData[@"picture"][@"data"][@"url"];

AsyncImageView *DescimageRight = [[AsyncImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4,4,146,146)];
DescimageRight.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
DescimageRight.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
DescimageRight.tag=999;
DescimageRight.imageURL=[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
[self.view addSubview:DescimageRight];
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would first like to understand what is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem:

The code is correct, and the image is also loaded correctly.

The problem was that I set a breakpoint to the last line of the code, i.e. to

```
}]; // breakpoint was set here
```

Apparently, when the debugger stops there, it left already the scope of the completion handler, and `image` was already `nil`.
After I inserted a dummy statement behind the assignment to `image`, and set the breakpoint to this dummy statement, everything was OK.

Sorry for bothering you.